# Populating listview with custom object

Tags: android, listview

i have a  arraylist of a custom object (NewsFeedObj). i would like to populate a listview using  the variables in NewsFeedObj. When i run the code i get a blank screen. Whats wrong?

```
 class Sadapter extends ArrayAdapter<NewsFeedObj>
  {
  Context context;
   int j;
    NewsFeedObj o = new NewsFeedObj();
     ArrayList<NewsFeedObj> l;
public Sadapter(Context context,int i,ArrayList<NewsFeedObj> g) 
{
    super(context,i,g);
    this.context=context;
    this.l=g;
    this.j=i;

    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.newfeed_layout,parent,false);
    //row.findViewById(id)
    TextView Text=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.Description);
    o=l.get(position);
    Text.setText( o.get_description());


    return row;
}




        }
```

Comment: show your code where you setAdapter()

Comment: ListView lis = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
       Sadapter A = new Sadapter(this,R.layout.newfeed_layout,NewsObjs);
       
       lis.setAdapter(A);

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement getter methods for array adapter. I think it might be the source of your issue..

Comment: The arrayadapter will look for the getter methods like getItemId(), getItem(), getCount() and getPosition(). So try to override those methods..

Comment: Change the line View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.newfeed_layout,parent,false);
as View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.newfeed_layout,null);

Answer (score 0):

Change the `getView()` method

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View row= convertView;
        if (view == null) {// Added check
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)   context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.newfeed_layout,parent,false);
        }
        NewsFeedObj  o=l.get(position);// Changed here
        TextView Text=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.Description);

        Text.setText( o.get_description());


        return row;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.newfeed_layout,parent,false);
```

should be this

```
View row=inflater.inflate(list_row.xml,null);
```

if you are using some layout for each row (for example list_row.xml)